# Compile typescript code into a single file with NX

Tags: typescript, nrwl, nx-workspace

I have this typescript project with just a couple of files; one main file which imports the others. It is not very important for my question, but when I compile it with webpack to javascript I get a single file without imports or requires, everything is inlined. For example, if I copy the content of that single file into my browser it just runs fine.

So, now I would like to move this project into a nx workspace. I guess that this project will become an `app` (not a lib) but how do I instruct nx to compile it into a selfcontained single file. Is this possible?

Any help/guidance will be appreciated!

Comment: did you manage to find any answers?

Comment: Nope, and because I don't need it right now, I stopped searching. If you know how to do this I'm still very interested!!